# "conda env list" claiming env is not a valid subcommand

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed conda. I created a new virtual environment. I restarted the computer and when I want to run it I get an error like this. Could you help?

```
C:\Windows\system32>conda env list
```

Error:

```
usage: conda [-h] {unpack,pack,convert,version,help} ...
conda: error: invalid choice: 'env' (choose from 'unpack', 'pack', 'convert', 'version', 'help')
```

Comment: Try `conda help` ? Which version are you using?

Comment: I try `conda version` but output like this "wheel 0.35.1"

Comment: That's all the output?

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/upl1ia) I really can't understand this error

Comment: How did you install `conda`? The current output looks to me like someone ran `pip install conda-pack` or `pip install conda-build`, but didn't actually install Conda proper. Could you please add the output of `where conda-pack` and `where conda` to the question?

Comment: I installed conda with .exe. After installing I created a virtual environment for "python=3.5". I ran `conda install opencv` and   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` then I encountered this error. After uninstalling conda i did clean install. It is working now, but I don't know what to do if I encounter this error again